# How to plot bar graphs of grouped groups of pairs in R?

Tags: r, plot, graph, ggplot2, grouping

I have a dataframe as:

```
Sex Tissue  Stage   Mean    SE
M   X   Larva   9.2 1.3
F   X   Larva   8.4 1.1
M   Y   Larva   9.2 1.4
F   Y   Larva   7.4 0.3
M   X   Pupa    2.1 0.1
F   X   Pupa    5.3 0.2
M   Y   Pupa    9.5 0.5
F   Y   Pupa    2.5 0.1
M   Z   Pupa    6.3 0.4
F   Z   Pupa    9.2 1.1
M   X   Adult   1.2 0.1
F   X   Adult   3.1 0.2
M   Y   Adult   6.3 0.5
F   Y   Adult   9.2 0.6
M   Z   Adult   1.2 0.1
F   Z   Adult   2.3 0.1
```

How can I create a bar graph formatted as shown below (but also with standard error bars too) where all of the M's are the same color and all of the F's are the same colour?

```
100 |               _     _ _    _         
    |  _   _       | |  _| | |  | |  _   _  
    | | | | |_     | |_| | | |  | | | | | |  
Mean| | |_| | |   _| | | | | |  | | | | | |_
    | | | | | |  | | | | | | |  | |_| |_| | |
 0  |_|_|_|_|_|__|_|_|_|_|_|_|__|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
       M F M F    M F M F M F    M F M F M F
        X   Y      X   Y   Z      X   Y   Z 
        Larva         Pupa          Adult
```

Data

```
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Sex Tissue  Stage   Mean    SE
M   X   Larva   9.2 1.3
F   X   Larva   8.4 1.1
M   Y   Larva   9.2 1.4
F   Y   Larva   7.4 0.3
M   X   Pupa    2.1 0.1
F   X   Pupa    5.3 0.2
M   Y   Pupa    9.5 0.5
F   Y   Pupa    2.5 0.1
M   Z   Pupa    6.3 0.4
F   Z   Pupa    9.2 1.1
M   X   Adult   1.2 0.1
F   X   Adult   3.1 0.2
M   Y   Adult   6.3 0.5
F   Y   Adult   9.2 0.6
M   Z   Adult   1.2 0.1
F   Z   Adult   2.3 0.1")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the spacing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `ggplot2` version. The code below places "F" or "M" below each bar. You can also choose not to include these letters and instead place a legend next to the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

dd$Stage = factor(dd$Stage, levels=c("Larva","Pupa","Adult"))

pd = position_dodge(0.9)

ggplot(dd, aes(Tissue, Mean, colour=Sex)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=pd, fill="grey95", lwd=1) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Sex, y=-0.5), position=pd, size=3.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean - SE, ymax=Mean + SE), width=0.1, position=pd) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Stage, switch="x", scales="free_x", space="free_x") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.background=element_rect(fill=NA, colour=NA),
        strip.text.x=element_text(size=12)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.5, max(dd$Mean + dd$SE))) +
  guides(fill=FALSE, colour=FALSE) +
  labs(x="")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Exactly as I was envisioning.  Lots of parameters I need to understand there.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions about the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base r version

```
dd$Stage <- factor(dd$Stage, levels = unique(dd$Stage))

bp <- barplot(dd$Mean, space = c(0, diff(as.numeric(dd$Stage)) != 0),
              col = c('tomato','dodgerblue2')[as.numeric(dd$Sex)],
              names.arg = dd$Sex, las = 1)
arrows(bp, dd$Mean, bp, dd$Mean + dd$SE,
       angle = 90, code = 3, xpd = NA, length = .1)

## text
tt <- tapply(bp, list(dd$Tissue, dd$Stage), mean)
text(c(tt), -2.5, labels = rownames(tt), xpd = NA)

tt <- tapply(bp, list(dd$Stage), mean)
text(c(tt), -3.5, labels = names(tt), xpd = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rawr, looks great too!